# Minimize difference in tower heights - TestCase issue

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

This is the question text:

> Given an array arr[] denoting heights of N towers and a positive integer K, you have to modify the height of each tower either by increasing or decreasing them by K only once. After modifying, height should be a non-negative integer.
> Find out what could be the possible minimum difference of the height of shortest and longest towers after you have modified each tower.

The question can be found here: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimize-the-heights3351/1#

My doubt was in the correctness of the algorithm I came up with. Here's the code:

```
int getMinDiff(int arr[], int n, int k) {
        // code here
        int mean = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mean += arr[i];
        }
        mean /= n;
        int minH = INT_MAX, maxH = INT_MIN;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] < mean)
            {
                if(arr[i] + k <= mean)
                {
                    arr[i] += k;
                }
                else
                {
                    int a = arr[i] + k - mean;
                    int b = mean - arr[i];
                    if(a < b)
                    {
                        arr[i] += k;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(arr[i] > mean)
            {
                if(arr[i] >= k)
                {
                    if(arr[i] - k >= mean)
                    {
                        arr[i] -= k;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int a = arr[i] - mean;
                        int b = mean - (arr[i] - k);
                        if(b < a)
                        {
                            arr[i] -= k;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] < minH)
            {
                minH = arr[i];
            }
            if(arr[i] > maxH)
            {
                maxH = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return maxH - minH;
    }
```

The code first finds the mean height of towers, then to minimize the difference, tries to bring height of each tower as close to the mean as possible. Then it calculates the difference between highest and lowest towers' heights.

This code, for the following test case:

```
   K = 5
   arr = 2 6 3 4 7 2 10 3 2 1
```

Produces the output

```
4
```

The given answer is

```
7
```

But, according to me, we can adjust the array as:

```
  2 6 3 4 2 2 5 3 2 6
```

Then the minimum and maximum heights are 2 and 6, so the answer should be 4. So, is there something wrong in the way I am approaching this problem?

I know this question has been asked before, but my query is about the specific solution algorithm.

Comment: Note: you have to modify *each* height, not a subset of them.

Comment: @Damien Oh! ok.. missed that point. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mean gets skewed by the number of elements having a certain value. But in this problem, the result is independent of how many elements match a particular value; we could have one element equal 20 or 1000 elements equal 20 and it won't affect the result.

```
2 6 3 4 7 2 10 3 2 1
k = 5


Ordered:

                     x (optimal)
+5:   6  7  8  9 11 12 15
      1  2  3  4  6  7 10
-5:  -4 -3 -2 -1  1  2  5
                        x (optimal)
```